# jQuery close slide when slideDown

Tags: jquery, slidedown, slideup

I want to close previous slide, when a slide is down (is active). How can i do this? Thanks for helping.

```
//PARAMS
var codeicons = jQuery('.codeparams').attr('data-icons');
var codecoloreven = jQuery('.codeparams').attr('data-even');
var codecolorhover = jQuery('.codeparams').attr('data-color');
var codebordercolor = jQuery('.codeparams').attr('data-border');

//DOWN  
jQuery('.code-question').toggle(function(){
    jQuery(this).next().slideDown('fast');

    if(codeicons == 'dark') {
    jQuery(this).addClass('code-active').addClass('codedarkdell').css({'box-shadow' : codebordercolor + ' 0 0 4px 0 inset' , 'border-color' : codebordercolor});
} else {
    jQuery(this).addClass('codelightdell').css({'box-shadow' : codebordercolor + ' 0 0 4px 0 inset' , 'border-color' : codebordercolor});
    };
},

/UP
    function(){
    jQuery(this).next().slideUp('fast');
    jQuery(this).removeClass('codedarkdell').removeClass('codelightdell').css({'box-shadow': '', 'border-color': ''});
    });
```

Comment: How your HTML looks like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple script which can help you:

```
$('.code-question').click(function(){
        //Close all which are open
        $('.code-answer').slideUp();
        // check if clicking on active one
        if ($(this).next().is(':visible')) { 
            //Close it if open
            $(this).next().slideUp('fast');     
        } else {
            //Open it if not
            $(this).next().slideDown('fast');       
        }

    });
```

Your code have some more condition which you can include.

Comment: You are awesome!! Thank you so so much :)

Comment: It's a good idea to first apply the jquery .stop method before starting another animation. So you'd have this: $(this).next().stop().slideUp('fast'). Otherwise jquery will wait for any other animations to finish before applying the next one which can result is some strange UI behavior.